# vscode not picking up .eslintrc settings

Tags: javascript, node.js, visual-studio-code, eslint

VSCode shows `unnecessary escape character error` - `no-useless-escape` setting.

But the .eslintrc has the following settings and does not contain the `no-useless-escape` settings:

```
{
    "root": true,
    "parserOptions": {
        "ecmaVersion": 6,
        "sourceType": "script"
    },
    "env": {
        "node": true,
        "browser": false
    },
    "extends": "eslint:recommended",
    "rules": {
        "semi": ["error", "always"],
        "indent": ["error", 4, {
            "VariableDeclarator": 1,
            "SwitchCase": 1,
            "MemberExpression": 1,
            "ArrayExpression": "first"
        }],
        "no-mixed-requires": "off",
        "no-restricted-imports": "off",
        "no-undef":"off",
        "no-console":"off",
        "no-trailing-spaces": "error",
        "no-unused-vars": "warn",
        "no-empty": ["error", {"allowEmptyCatch": true}]
    }
}
```

My workspace setting refer to the .eslintrc file correctly:

`"eslint.options": {"configFile": ".eslintrc"}`

What is wrong here? Are there some global configurations that need to be overridden?

Comment: You are extending `eslint:recommended` ruleset. It has the `no-useless-escape` rule. Check here for the list of rules that `eslint:recommended` has. https://eslint.org/docs/rules/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Saugat Acharya already mentioned the cause for the problem in the comments.
To fix it you just turn that rule explicitly off by adding the following rule to your `eslint.rc` file:

```json
{
    "rules": {
        "no-useless-escape": "off" 
    }
}
```